# How to find the maximum x value of a function?

Tags: python, function, max, exponential, absolute-value

I need to find the maximum `x` value associated to the maximum `y` value of the following function that I plot using Python `matplotlib` module:

```
# Import modules
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 

# Define the function
x = np.arange(0., 1000, 0.2)
y = np.abs(-np.exp(-x/1068)+np.exp(-x/46))

# Plot
plt.title("") 
plt.xlabel("x") 
plt.ylabel("y") 
plt.plot(x,y) 
plt.grid()
```

Hence, the trend is this one:

[image: plot]

If I use the `max()` function in such way:

```
print(max(y))
```

It prints only the maximum y value (that in this case is equal to `0.8306243772229114`). How can I do to have also the maximum x value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x` is an np.array and you want to find the `x` associated with the maximum `y`, you can use [np.argmax](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html).

```
x_max = x[np.argmax(y)]
```